# How to solve permission denied inside docker container?

Tags: docker, file

I am using the docker file for project [API Sprout](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/apisprout).

I want to launch the executable inside the docker container on a local file called `open_api.json`. Following the README, I run:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -v $(pwd)open_api.json:/api.json danielgtaylor/apisprout /api.json
```

But it fails with

```
[..datetime...] open /tmp/api.json: permission denied
```

How should I give the right permission / user to the file or container?

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the api.json file the correct permissions. 
for test give use: 
`chmod 777 api.json`
. if it works change the permissions to something more restricted 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-navigating-ownership.html

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work :( I don't quite know the permission scheme for docker, and can't seem to get it working!